# Product configurator doesn't work -.-

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I built a WooCommerce configurator on my landingpage, but unfortuantely it doesn't work. Console shows problem with JS code because of .hasclass() which I just don't get - can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

HTML:

```
<div id="amounts">
<button type="button" class="amount-button dreiriegel" value="6,50€" name="7,47€">
  <h2>3 Natural Energy-Riegel</h2>
</button>
<button type="button" class="amount-button zwoelfriegel" id="selected" value="23,88€" name="29,88">
  <h2>12 Natural Energy-Riegel</h2>
  <span>Du sparst xyz</span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="amount-button vierundzwanzigriegel" value="44,90€" name="59,76€">
  <h2>24 Natural Energy-Riegel</h2>
  <span>Du sparst yz</span>
</button>
</div>

<div id="offer-price"></div>
<div id="normal-price"></div>

<div id="input_div">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="moins" onclick="minus()">
    <div value="1" id="count">1</div>
    <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
</div>

<form id=“bestell-button" action="/cart/?add-to-cart=294&variation_id=299&quantity=1&attribute_pa_variante=12-riegel" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="Jetzt bestellen">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#selected {
  background-color: green;
}

.amount-button {
  width: 100%;
}

.amount-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.amount-button:hover {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var selected_oprice = jQuery('#selected').val();  
  jQuery('#offer-price').html(selected_oprice);
  var selected_nprice = jQuery('#selected').attr("name");
  jQuery('#normal-price').html(selected_nprice);
});

jQuery(function($) {
  $('.amount-button').click(function() {
    $('.amount-button').not(this).removeAttr('id', 'selected');
    $(this).attr('id', 'selected');
  var selected_oprice = jQuery('#selected').val();
  jQuery('#offer-price').html(selected_oprice);
  var selected_nprice = jQuery('#selected').attr("name");
  jQuery('#normal-price').html(selected_nprice);
  });
});

var count = 1;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");

function plus(){
  count++;
  countEl.value = count;
  countEl.innerHTML = count;
  }
function minus(){
  if (count > 1) {
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
    countEl.innerHTML = count;
  }
}  

function getVariation(){

  var dieses=jQuery(this);  

  if (dieses.hasClass("dreiriegel")) {
    return 297;
  }  
  else if (dieses.hasClass("zwoelfriegel")) {
    return 299;
  }
  else if (dieses.hasClass("vierundzwanzigriegel")) {
    return 300;
  }
}

function getAttribute(){

  var jenes=jQuery(this); 

  if (jenes.hasClass("dreiriegel")) {
    return 3-riegel;
  }  
  else if (jenes.hasClass("zwoelfriegel")) {
  return 12-riegel;
  }
  else if (jenes.hasClass("vierundzwanzigriegel")) {
    return 24-riegel;
  }
}

function getLink(){
  var href=window.location;
  var amount=document.getElementById("#count").value;
  var attribute=jQuery("#selected").getVariation();
  var variante=jQuery("#selected").getAttribute();

  href=href+"cart/?add-to-cart=294&variation_id="+variante+"&quantity="+amount+"&attribute_pa_variante="+attribute;

  return href;
}
```

Comment: 1. Please post the exact error message, 2. Replace  `“` `„` etc. with proper `"`

Comment: What is with all these different quotation marks? O.o, [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com), `document.getElementById()` doesn't understand CSS selectors, the value of `href` in `getLink()` is not a valid url

Comment: A `.hasClass` error usually occurs when `hasClass` is being called on an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: Quotes have been the first error, no way... TextEdit on Mac... -.- Thanks so much! Unfortunately getLink() ist still not working correctly :(